# Activity.recreate() copies the list

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-recyclerview

The app I'm working on is loading news from the internet. On the main `Activity` I have a `RecyclerView` with the selection of topics. All the content is loaded and updated in the `onResume()` method. The reasons for that is that I want to update the quantity of news and all of this activity's content whenever I am back on this `Activity`. I also have a preferences `Activity`. It is pretty standart.

In my activity I have a `listener`:

```
SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener listener = new SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() {
            public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
                recreate();
            }
        }
```

Whenever I get to the Settings menu and back I have my `RecyclerView` with changed values but I also get a duplicate of each item in list.

However in my `onResume()` method I have these lines of code:

```
sa.removeAllItemsFromList();
        sa.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

`sa.removeAllItemsFromList()` is my method that does this: `siteList.removeAll(siteList);`. Pretty simple and straight forward. So the question is: why do I get a duplicate and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why do I get a duplicate  ?

Because you are calling list creation login in `onResume()`.  When you go forward and backward `onResume()` method calls ,That will created list data and add to list

> how do I fix it?

Use `HashSet` instead of `ArrayList`

**HashSet contains unique elements only.**

[Use of HashSet](http://www.javatpoint.com/HashSet-class-in-collection-framework)

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. I will test it right ahead. Though I still have a question. Why doesn't `removeAllItemsFromList()` work? Isn't it supposed to delete all the elements and create new ones instead?

Comment: thank you for the advice though in my case it didn't work. I have totally no idea why. I have rearranged the activity cycle in my app and it seems to work now. Thank you for your advices once again. They were helpful